# How do I bind a Jquery submit to a form_tag form submission action in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ujs

In my rails app I'm submitting a range of forms via AJAX - normally via a modal. In order to do so I use the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(form).on('submit', function(event) {
  form = $(this).attr('id');
  selector = $('form#' + form)
  $(document).bind('ajaxError', selector, function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
    // note: jqxhr.responseJSON undefined, parsing responseText instead
    $(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) );
  });
});
```

This pulls any error messages and runs them through the `render_form_errors` function which then posts the errors to an error block on the form.

In order to render the code in a more attractive way I've started using "form_tag" submission in Rails:

```
 <%= form_tag('/sale_qualifiers', method: :post, remote: true) do -%>
    <%= fields_for :sale_qualifier do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id %>
        <%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id %>
          <tr id="form#sale_qualifier_submit">
            <td><%= @question.question_text %></td>
        <td>
        <%= ff.fields_for :answer_attributes do |answer| %>
            <div class="form-group">
            <% if @question.answer_type == 'Text Field' %>
                <%= answer.text_area :answer_text, :placeholder => "Enter your answer"%>
            <% end %>
            <% if @question.answer_type == 'Datetime' %>
                <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
                <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, :placeholder => "YYYY/MM/DD" %>
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                </span>
            </div>
        <% end %>
        <% if @question.answer_type == 'Boolean' %>
            <%= answer.select :answer_text, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]] %>
        <% end %>
            <span class="warning-block"></span>
            <span class="help-block"></span>
            </div>
        <% end %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", id: "sale_qualifier_submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, autocomplete: 'off' %>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>     
<% end %>
```

The result of this code is that the `submit_tag` does not sit within the form in the produced html - which it does when the `form_for` method is used. As such my Jquery doesn't bind to the submit action, and the code:

```
$(form).on('submit', function(event) {
  form = $(this).attr('id');
  selector = $('form#' + form)
```

Doesn't work either - because the entire form has a different set of ids and classes when using form_tag and they don't fit together organically like they do when Rails produces the entire form.

Can anyone suggest a Jquery method to grab the closest form-group to the submit button on submit, then bind this action to it if there's an AjaxError?

Do let me know if you need more info to help out.

Comment: You're using "remote: true", so the event is handled and discarded by ujs. You can bind to other events: https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/ajax

Comment: Thanks Geoffroy. I'm also using "remote: true" on the form_for version, and the attached JQuery works with that well enough as it binds to the form on submit. What I'm trying to understand is how to bind to the html generated by the form_tag on submit.

Answer (score 1):

It feels a bit "hacky" but I've gotten this working thanks to the link Geoffroy posted above and by just directly targeting my form:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(event) {
$(document).bind('ajaxError', 'form#new_sale_qualifier', function(event, jqxhr, settings, exception){
    // note: jqxhr.responseJSON undefined, parsing responseText instead
    $(event.data).render_form_errors( $.parseJSON(jqxhr.responseText) );
  });
});
```

Explicitly declaring the correct selector to bind the event to. It would be nicer if I could extract this info from the html - I feel it would be less susceptible to breaking in the future.